# Firestore keeps saying "fetch is not defined" on electron with vue

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, electron

I'm trying to get firebase firestore to work in electron. Firebase is initialized fine but when I try to run firestore, it says:

```
Error adding document:  ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at e (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/lite/index.browser.esm2017.js?:3242:30)
    at nn (webpack:///./node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/lite/index.browser.esm2017.js?:3243:10)
    .
    .
    .
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Desktop\Projects\casedb\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
```

I'm pretty sure that's happening because firestore is thinking it's running on the web and has access to `fetch` while it's actually running on node.js.

Now, I'm not sure what to do to make this work. I'm using a [vue-cli plugin](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) to use electron with vue. I've gone through their [documentation](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#native-modules) and tried the following.

1. Added firebase and firestore as a native dependency
2. Tried running my test script in a normal node.js environment
3. Tried using require instead of import

None of these have worked so far. From what I can gather by googling for 8 hours, it probably has something to do with webpack. But I can't figure out what to do.

Here is my `vue.config.js` which configures the cli plugin:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      externals: [
        "pouchdb-node",
        "firebase",
        "firebase/firestore",
        "firebase/firestore/lite",
        "firestore",
      ],
      preload: "src/preload.js",
      nodeIntegration: true,
      builderOptions: {
        nsis: {
          oneClick: false,
          createDesktopShortcut: true,
          perMachine: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Here is my firebase test script just in case:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore/lite";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCwzmIhPhUxB7uFsCHlWhARTiSzMylDn0A",
  // authDomain: "casedb-29442120.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "casedb-29442120",
  storageBucket: "casedb-29442120.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "354561150712",
  appId: "1:354561150712:web:3db5b0d737be49a90bf50d",
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();

export const syncWithDB = async () => {
  try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "records"), {
      first: "Ada",
      last: "Lovelace",
      born: 1815,
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Apparently you are on the right track, based on similar [issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/4663) (with possible [workarounds](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1797#issuecomment-498474850)). It seems that your setup makes the Firebase SDK behave as running in the browser and not through Nodejs. I think that opening an issue in the Vuejs plugin [repo](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) could help you better since you have a very specific setup.